Failure Azure REST API for creating new Agent Pool
I am referring to this microsoft-learn documentation to create a NodePool in AKS. As per the document, You would need to send a PUT request towards:
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.NetworkCloud/kubernetesClusters/{kubernetesClusterName}/agentPools/{agentPoolName}?api-version=2023-07-01

For example, lets say the values are:

subscriptionId = abc
resourceGroupName = rg1
kubernetesClusterName = aks-us-east
agentPoolName = poolakstesting1

with some body parameters (Here is what i am passing):
{
    "properties": {
        "vmSize": "Standard_D16s_v5", 
        "enableAutoScaling": True,
        "count": 1,
        "minCount": 0, 
        "maxCount": 12,
        "maxPods": 75,
        "mode": "User",
        "OSType": "Linux"
    }
}

However, I am getting this error:
{
"code": "InvalidParameter",
"details": null,
"message": "The value of parameter agentPoolProfile.name is invalid. Please see https://aka.ms/aks-naming-rules for more details.",
"subcode": "",
"target": "agentPoolProfile.name"

My primary suspicion is that I would need to furnish the name of the to-be-created agentpool along with payload (apart from the PUT endpoint). But, none of the document point out this.

The issue has been identified.
Basically, there is a check on the number of characters in AKS node pool name. Currently it is set to 12 characters. As you can see that my agent pool name has breached this limit.
Providing a smaller name worked out for me.
